# Web API authentication using more than one Database

Tags: android, mysql, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, retrofit

I have created a sample WEB API using `MySQL` DB. The authentication used in it is [Basic Authentication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZnmhyZzKgs). The authentication is user based as I have created a user table in it and while converting it to 64 bit encoding and matching it with the username and password of the user.

Now I want to created an actual WEB API. There are two databases both in MySQL. WEB API will be created using a Database 1. The request will be sent from an android application which is having a Database 2. Now the main discussion is for `Authentication` point of view. As far as I have studied [Retrofit](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit) is one of the best method for authentication in android application development. Now, for authentication the user info is in `DB1`(from which the app is created) and it will hit on WEB API which is created on `DB2`. If the database will be single than it won't be an issue with me but as far as there are two databases so there is some problem.

**What can i do?**

1. Copy all the user data to `DB2` and generate a authentication. 
   This step will be easy but in real-time the user will me more so I have to copy all there data again and again.
2. Create a dummy user in `DB2` and pass all the authentication while using it.
3. Use both Databases in my WEB API project. Use `DB1` to get authentication and also verify it, after verification then allow the WEB API to be accessed. I am not sure how this method will works.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need 2 API's but you can always have them talk to each other which also means more API calls so you better have a reason to use two API's.

When you get username and password (or email ) you need to try to match it with the password you store in your API so you can either store all user information in on place including username and password or you can call the authentication API every time you need to authenticate a user over http request which means server one is calling server to waiting for him to respond and then serve the user his response upon valid authentication

Comment: No the API will be only one, and it will only be created using the `DB2`. My question is again on authentication, that how can I authenticate it as the request would be generated through the mobile app. The app also have some API's but all of them are under same `DB` and when ever a call is made from the app, username's `auth Key` is passed in the header. Again, this all works under the same `DB` but here the condition is different as I am using some other Database to create the API, so how can I authenticate it ?

Comment: The fact that you are communicating with android native app shouldn't affect the authentication process. I still don't understand the problem, you got an authentication process which call the API with password and username parameters am I right?

Comment: Let's just not mix things. First of all we will just understand how the app works. There are several API's in the the app. The is native android based and `PHP` is used as a back-end. Whenever a call is made to an `API` it sends the authentication to the same server and same DB and gets the response from it.

Comment: But now, I am creating a new API in `dot net`, which is using a separate database and it will be hosted on separate server. But the request will be generated from the same app, here I am confused how should I authenticate the API?

Comment: You can use authentication tokens and minimize the API calls to the old API. Having the some data in 2 different API is not scalable and maintains nightmare so you better off calling the old API every time an access token is expired which can be days or months . Again assuming you must have the old API as part of your application for other stuff